# Selenium+Jenkins+Chromedriver = WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally

Tags: selenium, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I have problem with running my Selenium tests in Jenkins. 
A result of execution is always:

> WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start:
>   exited abnormally

My tests are written in Robot Framework and are using Chromium webdriver.
I'm setting needed paths in my command, which looks like this:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/chromium-browser; export PATH=$PATH:/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver; . /home/michal/robot_env/bin/activate; robot -L TRACE /home/michal/project_robot/tests
```

And when I run this command manually in terminal IT WORKS fine (Chromium starts automatically and the test goes on). 
So the problem suppose to be in Jenkins. I have installed Xvfb plugin, but it didn't help.
Additionally, in */etc/init.d/jenkins* I put these lines:

> /usr/bin/X :0 vt7 -ac
>
> export DISPLAY=:0
>
> xhost +

And once again - nothing changed. What else should I set or check?

Comment: Is Jenkins running under a different user then your terminal session? Have you checked if all the environment variables in both situations are the same?

Comment: Does it involve screen to be active and UI up on screen Or Could run even silently?

Comment: @A.Kootstra Jenkins is running under a different user, but this user has the same env variables as terminal.

Comment: @Waman Yes, I would like to have a view on what happens currently in a test (Chromium window needs to be visible for normal user).

Comment: Since triggering from Jenkins would be more of a console trigger & selenium is something which needs UI. I would suggest you try to schedule a task in the machine under test ( Jenkins slave ) which will run the selenium tests, rather then directly triggering from Jenkins.. I mean to say  "Jenkins --> Schedule a task to run next minute in Slave --> task will run the selenium tests". So when Selenium tests are run, it is something which is triggered on the slave and not a console trigger hence u see UI! Hope i dint confuse you :)

Comment: @Waman My tests are triggered by post-commit hook from Git, so it is more complicated than I described it in my question, but thank you for the suggestion, I'll dig this subject more deeper ;)

Answer (score 0):

i got stuck same way.
The problem is that jenkins has it own user, called jenkins, and jenkins user cannot open the browser.

if you try to make "su jenkins" and then "chromium-browser" you obtain the display error.

That because you obtain this issue. The problem is not the webdriver, the problem is the user.

i removed the jenkins user created by jenkins and i createad a normal user called jenkins before installing jenkins.

then i installed jenkins.

now jenkins user can run the test (because it can open the browser) but jenkins itself will not load anymore.